# MySql Query Where not working correctly

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to query a database to select only the records where show = 0

Here is my query, but it returns both 0 and 1 for the show column

```
SELECT * FROM menu WHERE 'SHOW' = 0;
```

Table Structure:

```
Table: menu
Columns:
  id    int(2) AI PK
  url   text
  name  text
  title text
  show  int(1)
```

Data in Table

```
| id |     url     | name | title | show |
------------------------------------------
| 1  | /index.php  | Home | Home  | 0    |
| 2  | /index2.php | Home | Home2 | 1    |
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the single quotes.  If you use any quotes, use backquotes:

```
SELECT * FROM menu WHERE `SHOW` = 0;
```

The problem is that `'SHOW'` is a string, not a column name.  When it is compared to an integer (`0`), then it is converted to an integer.  Because the first character is a letter, the conversion results in `0` . . . and the condition is true.

Answer (score 4):

You mustn't use this kind of quotes. Instead of, use :

```
SELECT * FROM menu WHERE `SHOW` = 0;
```